# Application works fine in development but having a crash on opening an AdHoc build

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift project and I have used Objective-C frameworks installed via CocoaPods. The application is for iOS 8 and above devices.

The application works fine in development but it crashes when opening an AdHoc build.

I have
verified my runpath search paths are correct: @executable_path/Frameworks and @loader_path/Frameworks
Set EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT to YES on the application target and all Pods targets

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've installed AFNetworking framework incorrectly.

Comment: I have installed using pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run app in `Release mode`.

To do it:

1. Go to "Project" command in an Xcode application menu and chose "Edit Scheme"(Shortcut: ⌘< )
2. Select "Run Project name" in left pane
3. In right pane, under "Info" tab change "Build Configuration" to "Release"

Or maybe you have this problem:

> By default cocoapods will only link the generated libpod.a with Debug
>   and Release. You can add it to additional configuration, by highlight
>   "Project" > "Deployment Target" > "Configurations" > and set the
>   "Configuration File" to Pods

Comment: Did you try to run it on real device?

Comment: Yes i am running on a real device . When i use a development profile it works fine but when i make an archive (ad hoc ) build it doen't work on the device

Comment: also check your images and try to install AFNetworking manually

Comment: Manually adding the frameworks are working just fine , but i need with the pods , i think am missing some setting or flag may b in new version of xcode .